# Calling Raspberry Pi from ASP.NET to send a SMS remotely

Tags: php, python, asp.net, raspberry-pi, sms

Just discovered the amazing `Raspberry Pi 3` and I am trying to learn how to use it in one of my projects.

Setup:

- `ASP.NET` app on `Azure`.
- `RPi`:

  - software: `Raspbian`, `PHP`, `Apache 2`, and `MariaDB`.
  - has internet access and a web server a configured.
- 3G dongle for SMS sending, connected to the `RPi`.

Desired scenario:

- when a specific button within the `ASP` app is clicked:

  - through `jQuery` `$.ajax()` the `RPi`'s ip is called with the parameters `phoneNumber` and `smsType`.
- then the `RPi`:

  - fetches the SMS text from a `MariaDB` database based on the `smsType` parameter.
  - invokes a `Python` script using the `PHP` `exec("python sendSms.py -p phoneNumber -m fetchedText", $output)` (i.e. with the phone number and the fetched text):

    - script will send the `AT` command(s) to the dongle.
    - script will return `true` or `false` based on the action of the dongle.
- `echo` the `$output` to tell the `ASP` what is the status.
- finally, the `ASP` will launch a `JavaScript` `alert()` saying if it worked or not.

This is what I need to accomplish. For most of the parts I found resources and explanations. However, before starting on this path I want to understand few things:

- General questions (if you think they are not appropriate, please ignore this category):

  - What are the (logical) pitfalls of this scenario?
  - What would be a simpler way to approach this?
- Specific questions:

  - Is there a size limit to consider when passing parameters through the `url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What are the (logical) pitfalls of this scenario?
  My opion would be to pass the data and the two fields (phoneNumber and SmsType) through a POST request rather then an GET request because you can send more data in an post request and encapsulate it with JSON making it easier to handle the data.
- What would be a simpler approch ?
  Maybe not simple but more elegant, extend the python script with something like flask and build the webserver right into the python script, saves you running a webserver with php!

Comment: Sounds more elegant indeed. Do you have any resources on building that in python? If so, can you please update your answer. I think this is all I need!